# simple html dom parser specific div class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

i have html file

```
<div class= "aaaa">
 <div class="media"></div>
 <div class="media"></div>

</div>
<div class="bbbb">
 <div class="media"></div>
 <div class="media"></div>

</div>
```

this my code

```
foreach($html->find('div[class=media] img') as $media)
   {
```

find all image in 'class media' ,but i need not show 'class media in class bbbb,
how to block 'div class media' on 'div class bbbb' not display

Answer (score 0):

You would just do:

```
$html->find('.aaa .media img')
```